# JMESPath filtering in s3

Tags: boto3, jmespath

I have an object in s3 that looks like this:

```json
{'Key': '1111_redshift_us-east-1_dev-ue1-rs-analytics_useractivitylog_2021-05-01T20:18.gz', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 24, 19, 14, 40, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ETag': '"60377db54e3bbcfe7d569b8ea029cfa3-1"', 'Size': 7, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}
```

and the page from the page_iterator looks like this:

```
PAGE: {'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'IsTruncated': False, 'Contents': [{'Key': '1111_redshift_us-east-1_dev-ue1-rs-analytics_connectionlog_2021-05-01T20:18.gz', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 24, 19, 14, 40, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ETag': '"60377db54e3bbcfe7d569b8ea029cfa3-1"', 'Size': 7, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}, {'Key': '1111_redshift_us-east-1_dev-ue1-rs-analytics_notvalidname_2021-05-01T20:18.gz', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 24, 19, 14, 40, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ETag': '"60377db54e3bbcfe7d569b8ea029cfa3-1"', 'Size': 7, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}, {'Key': '1111_redshift_us-east-1_dev-ue1-rs-analytics_useractivitylog_2021-05-01T20:18.gz', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 24, 19, 14, 40, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ETag': '"60377db54e3bbcfe7d569b8ea029cfa3-1"', 'Size': 7, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}, {'Key': '1111_redshift_us-east-1_dev-ue1-rs-analytics_userlog_2021-05-01T20:18.gz', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 24, 19, 14, 40, tzinfo=tzutc()),
```

and I'm trying to do the filter like this:

```
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)
    print(f"FILTER: {filter}")
    # filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search(filter) if filter else page_iterator
    for page in page_iterator:
        print(f"PAGE: {page}")
        for obj in page.get("Contents", []):
            print(f"OBJECT: {obj}")
            yield obj
```

but I'm not getting objects back. Am I doing the JMESPath filter in `search` wrong? I'm going by these [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html#filtering-results-with-jmespath)

and my filter is this:

```
"Contents[?Key[?contains(@, 'useractivitylog') == `true`]]"
```

What a I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs can be terribly confusing. Here's a good reference, but even that can be a bit verbose. https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/07/27/advanced-aws-cli-jmespath-query/

There are three filters below, just comment/uncomment the different lines to see how they output the data.

Also, this traverses the entire bucket so it can be time consuming.

```
bucket='new-bucket-for-lists'
client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)
# filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("Contents[?contains(Key, '.py')] ")
# filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("Contents[?contains(Key, '.py')][Key, LastModified] ")
filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("Contents[?contains(Key, '.py')].LastModified ")
for key_data in filtered_iterator:
    print(key_data)
```

Comment: thanks so much. Is this usage of `contains` even outlined in the actual jmespath docs??!

Comment: It is https://jmespath.org/specification.html#functions  but unless one spends the time to really understand it, it's not very clear. But once I see it in action, it almost makes perfect sense.

Comment: out of curiosity, did you consider just doing the filtering using python/json and evaluating the key name? Wondering if this is truly faster as I have plenty of places I could use this.

Comment: It's just that I didn't see usage of `contains` without the @ symbol and so your usage is different than what I expected from their docs.

Comment: I did not, I've only used jmespath so far since boto3 supports it in the `search` feature so I figured it must be fast?

Comment: i did some comparisons. added it in new answer.

Answer (score 3):

Timing different AWS apis and jmespath implementations.

I used a folder and prefix where there around 1500 objects and tested retrieving all them vs a filtered set. Surprisingly, maybe, the `list_objects` endpoint is much slower than `list_objects_v2` endpoint.

Using jmespath is only slightly better than just iterating through the pages using python list comprehension. In the end, all the data is pulled and then filtered. Maybe for a larger directory the results would be more substantial.

```
%%timeit
keys_list = []
paginator = s3sr.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
for page in  paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
    # print(page)
    # bucket_object_paths = jmespath.search('Contents[*].Key', page)
    bucket_object_paths = jmespath.search("Contents[?contains(Key, 'straddles')].Key", page)
    keys_list.extend(bucket_object_paths)
len(keys_list)
# 450 ms ± 34.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) - 1460 objects
# 368 ms ± 13.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) - filtered

%%timeit
keys_list = []
paginator = s3sr.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
# use Delimiter to limit search to that level of hierarchy
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
    # keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents')]
    keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents') if 'straddles' in content['Key']]
    # print('keys in page: ', len(keys))
    keys_list.extend(keys)
len(keys_list)
# 448 ms ± 69.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) - 1460 objects
# 398 ms ± 31.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) - filtered

%%timeit
client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/')
keys_list = page_iterator.search("Contents[?contains(Key, 'straddles')].Key ")
# keys_list = page_iterator.search("Contents[*].Key ")
len(list(keys_list))
# 948 ms ± 170 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) - 1460 objects
# 885 ms ± 48.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```